# How do I change the date format in the header when printing with DotNetBrowser?

Tags: chromium, dotnetbrowser

The only localisation I could find is described here:
https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110018-chromium-language-localization

> DotNetBrowser allows configuring Chromium engine with specified
>   language (two letter code from ISO-639 e.g. "en", "de", "it", etc).
>   The language will be used for UI text messages localization (e.g. text
>   on the web page that's displayed when Chromium failed to load URL).
>
> By default, Chromium engine is configured to use .NET application
>   language that can be received from
>   theCultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name property. To configure Chromium
>   engine with .NET application language, DotNetBrowser extracts the
>   language from theCultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name property and passes
>   it to Chromium engine via the --lang Chromium switcher.
>
> If you need to change this default behavior, then you can configure
>   Chromium engine directly with specified language via Chromium--lang
>   switcher.

Unfortunately this does not seem to apply any date formatting (which makes sense as it only seems to pay attention to the language "en" and not the locale)

When I print, the header on every page has a date which is in US format. My customers are not in the US and giving them dates in US formats would be a disaster.

Is there any way to set the date format in DotNetBrowser / Chromium?

In Chrome Advanced Settings I can pick English New Zealand and English UK as languages and those settings do affect the printed page headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify English UK locale as "en-GB" as shown below:

```
BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches("--lang=en-GB");
```

Do not forget that this switcher should be set before you create any Browser instance.

This article describes how to set Chromium switchers: https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser-support/documentation/chromium-switches